# Random Graphs - Planarity

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

If I take a Random planar graph with $V$ vertices and $E$ edges, I would like to know the probability that it remains planar if I add in another random edge, I realise that there is probably no simple expression for this but is there any asymptotics or the like that would shed some light on it?

Comment: Interesting question, I think there is a theorem that a  majority of "large graphs" are non-planar. So, probably the interesting side  of question is for "small" graphs.

Comment: That seems intuitively reasonable, I guess an interesting question would be; how many edges can a graph have before it is more likely than not to be non-planar

Comment: The probability that a $V$-vertex, $E$-edge graph is planar seems easier to understand. (I would guess that at $E \sim \frac12 V$ when the random graph acquires a giant component is also when the random graph stops being planar). It's hard to find results about random planar graphs with $V$ and $E$ fixed.